# Setting emoji in string api 22

Tags: android

Hello I display String from resources wtih emoji coded in this way \uD83D\uDE09, on api 25 it works perfectly but on api 22 I got this error 
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0

when I delete emoji it works perfectly.

How should I code emoji? I don't want to change min api